# Why doesn't my FileSystemWatcher work?

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I got a `FileSystemWatcher`, when i make a file in the first directory it should be going to the 2nd as well. So I want the file to be overwritten when it already exists in the 2nd directory. It wont work. I got this:

```
 private void fileSystemWatcher1_Created(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {

            listBox1.Items.Add("File created> " + e.FullPath + " -Date:" + DateTime.Now);
            if (File.Exists(target+e.Name))
            {
                File.Delete(target+e.Name);
            }
            File.Copy(e.FullPath, Path.Combine(target, e.Name));
    }
```

and i got another problem:
It is showing when a file is created but not when it's renamed, deleted, changed.
Here is my code.:

```
private void fileSystemWatcher1_Changed(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!pause)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add("File changed> " + e.FullPath + " -Date:" + DateTime.Now);
        }

    }

    private void fileSystemWatcher1_Created(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {

            listBox1.Items.Add("File created> " + e.FullPath + " -Date:" + DateTime.Now);
            if (File.Exists(target+e.Name))
            {
                File.Delete(target+e.Name);
            }
            File.Copy(e.FullPath, Path.Combine(target, e.Name));
    }

    private void fileSystemWatcher1_Deleted(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!pause)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add("File deleted> " + e.FullPath + " -Date:" + DateTime.Now);
            File.Delete(target+e.Name);
        }
    }

    private void fileSystemWatcher1_Renamed(object sender, System.IO.RenamedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!pause)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add("File renamed> " + e.FullPath + " -Date:" + DateTime.Now);
        }
    }
        private void Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        fileSystemWatcher1.Path = source;
        if (!pause)
        {
            pause = true;
            Start.Text = "Pause";
            fileSystemWatcher1.EnableRaisingEvents = true;   
        }
        else
        {
            pause = false;
            Start.Text = "Start";
            fileSystemWatcher1.EnableRaisingEvents = false;

        }

    }
```

Comment: Seems like pause is true... Could you show us the code where you declare the FileSystemWatcher?

Comment: @John Smith: Can you paste the code where you are initializing the `FileSystemWatcher?`

Comment: @John Smith: Thanks - how are you hooking up the events too? Is it through the Properties tab?

Comment: Also.. Use Path.Combine instead of concatenating the strings.

Comment: @DominicZukiewicz What do you mean? This is like my whole code

Comment: @JohnSmith: One more q - do you have hundreds of files doing this, or 1 or 2?

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance Doesn't fix anything.

Comment: @JohnSmith: It won't know what methods to call when the events are raised. If it is calling the _Created, the wireup must be somewhere else. I was saying just check that the _Renamed, _Changed methods were also wired up

Comment: @DominicZukiewicz What do you mean with "wired up"?

Comment: @JohnSmith: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx

Comment: @DominicZukiewicz I fixed it already nvm but can you help with the other question i had?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if(!pause){

}
is causing the problem you have to remove it.